# develop a chrome extension to download pdfs from current page on browser?

Tags: javascript, popup, addeventlistener, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, execute-script

i want to develop a chrome extension but i ma new for the concept.

i need these characteristics:

for a web page which is opened on browser, e.g. google search results (https://www.google.com/search?q=Turkey+pdf), find all resulted items that has pdf link for download directly. then by click on a button in extension popup window, all found pdfs will be downloaded to pc considering manifest 3 version.

i use folowing codes but the download process is not started and these errors are presented in developer mode that i cant solve them;

-Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'download')

-Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'download')

as well here is my code parts:

```
//manifest.json

  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "PDF Downloader_Test4",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Download PDF links from Google search results",
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "downloads"], 
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.google.com/search?*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icon.png"
    }
  }
}


//background.js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  console.log('PDF Downloader Extension Installed');
});

// Message listener
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === 'executeContentScript') {
    // Execute content script to find and download PDF links
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      const activeTab = tabs[0];
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(activeTab.id, { file: 'content.js' });
    });
  }
});


//content.js

// Function to download PDFs
function downloadPDF(url) {
  chrome.downloads.download({ url: url });
}

// Find and download PDF links
function findAndDownloadPDFLinks() {
  const pdfLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href$=".pdf"]');
  pdfLinks.forEach(link => {
    downloadPDF(link.href);
  });
}

// Execute when the DOM is ready
findAndDownloadPDFLinks();


//popup.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>PDF Downloader</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>PDF Downloader</h1>
  <p>Click the button below to download PDF links from the current page:</p>
  <button id="downloadButton">Download PDFs</button>

  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

//popup.js

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // Add click event listener to the download button
  const downloadButton = document.getElementById('downloadButton');
  downloadButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // Send a message to the background script to initiate the download
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'downloadPDFs' });
  });
});
```

i will be so glad if any one could help me to solve that.

so thanks in advance

Comment: Use executeScript to return the href of the links, then use chrome.downloads API on the result.